# Remove file extension from a URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to make my site look more professional by removing the html endings from the pages..
ex. just leaving at http://33tpm.com/es/tienda

All the answers Ive found so far are so confusing that I don't really understand anything.. 
Can someone please help me out?

Thank you 
Thomas

Comment: This is called URL Rewriting. What platform are you using?

Comment: "I am trying to make my site look more professional" -- Why would it be more professional not to use the html ending? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Filetype suffix in the URL is not particularly useful information, because content-type is told in the http headers and one can usually assume the content being html, if no suffix is used. Keeping your URLs pretty (= human & machine friendly) is professional – although this includes lot of more than stripping the suffix.

Comment: @Joop: 
This is known as URL beautification. On my site, for example, all URLs read like www.example.com/lang/section/sub-section and so on, but everything goes through an index.php script that produces the common stuff (site logo, navigation, etc), and then retrieves the relevant content from DB or includes (or a mix of both).
With the "real" url (like /index.php?lang=en&section=foo&subs=bar) the user sees how the site is working; with the clean URLs (/en/foo/bar) the users see where they are: what do do you think is more useful to the average user?

Comment: @herenvardo: I already did understand why you would do such a thing and of course it's a good thing. Especially for sites where good SEO is required. What I did before was giving an item the '.something' suffix and a category without a suffix: E.g.: www.newssite.com/breaking-news/cars/bmw-is-going-green.html. The suffix gives me the idea I reached an end-point. All in all nothing is good or bad. Just what you like more. Right?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this without knowing what web server you are using.

On Apache, you would usually use mod_rewrite to change the appearance of URLs without changing the underlying file structure.  An example of hiding .html would be:

RewriteRule ^/some/directory/(.*)$ /some/directory/$1.html